# Embedding a finite group into $\operatorname{GL}_n( \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, gap

Let $G$ be a finite group. Having a concrete realisation of this finite group as a group of matrices is often helpful for calculations, which motivates the following questions.

> Question 1: Is there a good way to obtain the minimal $n$ such that $G$ embedds into $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ (meaning there is an injective homomorphism of G into $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$)? Is it possible to obtain such a minimal embedding via GAP?

> Question 2: Is there a good way to obtain the minimal $n$ such that $G$ embedds into $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ such that all matrices in the image have only entries 0 or 1 (or entries 0, 1 and -1)? Is it possible to obtain such a minimal embedding via GAP?

> Question 3: Is there a canonical such minimal embedding if we impose some further restrictions or nice properties of such maps?

Comment: Please try to include some form of context in your question, e.g. *why* do you want to do this? And why do you want Gap to do this for you?

Comment: It is already difficult computationally to find the smallest $n$ for which $G$ embeds into $S_n$, and I would guess that the problem is even more difficult  for ${\rm GL}_n({\mathbb Z})$.  If I was trying to solve that problem for some finite group $G$, then I would start by finding the irreducible rational representations of $G$ (which can all be written over ${\mathbb Z}$). They would typically not all be faithful but they might provide enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you for the comment. Can GAP find all irreducible representations over the rationals?

Answer (score 1):

I have no interest or experience with GAP, but here are some partial answers:

1. Every finite subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$ can be conjugated into $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$.  So it is enough to find the minimal dimensional rational representation.
2. Lemma: An 0-1 matrix with a 0-1 inverse is a permutation matrix.  So this is asking for finding a minimal faithful action of $G$ on a finite set.
3. Ignoring the faithfulness issue, finding a minimal non-trivial $G$-set is the same as finding a maximal order subgroup of $G$.